# Missing table content when printing in Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-office, printer, microsoft-word-2007

I have a formula sheet with lots of tables and ... formulas. I'm trying to print it, but it comes with some of the tables' contents empty. The print preview looks beautiful, it's just the final paper product that's missing these formulas.

Any idea how to resolve?

Answer (score 1):

I opened the same document in Word 2010, and it printed like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, updating from a PCL5 to a PCL6 or KX driver fixed it.